# Google Sheets Treemap Chart Tool-tip Showing Twice

Tags: google-sheets, charts, tooltip, treemap

Looking for assistance with a Google Sheets treemap chart. When I turn tool-tips on I get the value showing up twice. Tool-tips work fine with other chart types. How can I get the value to show only once as a tool-tip in a treemap?.

Here's an example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSag7IGwwqmgsVqpi9PMKPVMMidEU59GY6RvEWovXv1NrEsTXKjm4n7LS1HJasKjpBYeNUbX29645N5/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true

[image]